# Finding recurring characters in every line in text file

Tags: java

I have some lines of plain text:

> We, therefore, the Representatives of the united States of 
>   America, in General Congress, Assembled, appealing to the 
>   Supreme Judge of the world for the rectitude of our intentions,
>   do, in the Name, and by the Authority of the good People of 
>   these Colonies, solemnly publish and declare, That these United 
>   Colonies are, and of Right ought to be Free and Independent 
>   States; that they are Absolved from all Allegiance to the 
>   British Crown, and that all political connection between them 
>   and the State of Great Britain, is and ought to be totally 
>   dissolved; and that as Free and Independent States, they have 
>   full Power to levy War, conclude Peace, contract Alliances, 
>   establish Commerce, and to do all other Acts and Things which 
>   Independent States may of right do. And for the support of this 
>   Declaration, with a firm reliance on the protection of divine 
>   Providence, we mutually pledge to each other our Lives, our 
>   Fortunes and our sacred Honor.

I have to find all the characters that occur in every line ("We, therefore, the Representatives of the united States of America, in General Congress," is the first line). An example would be the letter d, as it shows up on every line.

Any hints or answers on how to do this?

Comment: For each line, create a set of all characters in the line.  Then compute the intersection of all the sets.  You can use [`retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) to compute an intersection.

Comment: This seems like a homework question. I recommend you read this: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Input String:

```
    String string = "a b c d e f g h\n"
            + "zzzzz a b zzzzz\n"
            + "kkkkkkk a b djjjjj\n"
            + "ddaaddfdf b  dfdfdf\n"
            + "asdfsadf b  asdfaqw\n";
    compare(string);
```

Comparator method:

```
public void compare(String string) {
    Pattern pattern = null;
    Matcher matcher = null;
    for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*(" + i + ").*(?:\\n(?=.*\\1.*).*)*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        matcher=pattern.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

As both a and b are common in all lines, therefore the output will be :

```
a
b
```

[Regex BreakDown](https://regex101.com/r/r4Sq5R/5)

Comment: why not `for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)`?  Using the actual characters instead of integers makes it clear what you're doing, and if you declare the index to be `char` then you don't have to convert it.

Comment: right you are... that will make it better readable ... updated

Answer (score 0):

First write and test a method that finds the common letters in two sets of characters.

```
 public String commonLetters(String a, String b) {
     ...
 }
```

Test it with tests like `assertEquals("bc", commonLetters("abc", "bcd"))`. You should be able to achieve this with basic string-handling. Don't worry yet about making it efficient. If it reads all the way through the second string for each character of the first, so be it.

Once you know this works, you have the tools to do a loop like (pseudocode):

```
String line = readLine();
String commonLettersSoFar = line;
while(line != null) {
    commonLettersSoFar = commonLetters(line, commonLettersSoFar);
    line = readLine();
}
return commonLettersSoFar;
```

Once this works, you can think about making it cleverer and more efficient. Consider making `commonLetters()` work with `Set<Character>` instead of `String` 
 (think about how you can convert a `String` into a `Set<Character>`). Look at the JavaDoc for `Set` and hunt for methods that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the implementation, Java already has it built in. Just let [Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) do the work for you.

Make a `HashSet<char>` for each line, then use `set.retainAll(otherSet)` and then the set will only contain the common elements of each line. (adapt as your requirements change)